# Swift3! Как программно отключить дисплей?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3, display

Как программно отключить дисплей в Xcode Swift3? К примеру, при разговоре по телефону, если закрыть датчик приближения - то отключается дисплей.

Comment: Вам нужно именно выключить или поведение как при звонке?

Comment: Нужно как при звонке, но если есть еще варианты напишите)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала поведения как при звонке пропишите:

```
UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true
```

Когда уже не нужно, соответственно

```
UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = false
```

Comment: Вот, да, это оно! только нужно тоже самое при нажатии кнопки. Нажал кнопку - выключился экран, тапнул на экран - Включился. Есть такое?) Либо нажал кнопку - экран в минимальную яркость, еще раз нажал - в обычную которая была. Хочу уменьшить расход батареи. Но нельзя никак в локскрин уходить, иначе у меня будут проблемы)

Comment: @IvanGT UIScreen.main.brightness = 0 яркость на минимум

Comment: Отлично, спасибо